# How to find (detect) table elements <Table class> in selenium with python and copy/save the contents in a file (excel file)

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Python & Selenium automation framework and need to understand how I can detect the information placed in the form of a table (please refer to the image attached) and write the information to an Excel file.

In the picture, there are 3 columns (Name, Username, Email Address) of some users (A-Z) and the highlighted right hand side portion shows the corresponding elements.

I do not know which (and how to) selector would work to identify each row until the last record in a for/while loop and to write the contents in a file.

Any help would really be appreciated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: xpath to table, iterate elements.

Comment: Do you had tried some code? Post please

Comment: I tried using the XPath selector as suggested by @Reedinationer and which looks like:                                                                                                                    
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") --This is the Xpath for very first (Name) <td> record
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
 wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
   wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])

Comment: I meant like `elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/div/table/tbody/tr/td")` (note the 's' in 'elements') then `for elem in elems:`

Comment: Apologies @Reedinationer, I could not comprehend your suggestion and I still am not able to construct the exact line of code with XPath...referring to the data I have, as attached previously.

Comment: @Vish I cannot help more without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise I would be speculating a solution and wasting your time (and more importantly mine). Perhaps you can review [how to ask better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which is suggested reading when making a new account.

Comment: @Reedinationer - What I meant is I couldn't achieve the desired outcome referring to the problem I have in hand. I will try again with your suggestion and post the updated results for further feedback from the experts.

Comment: Hi @Reedinationer, I have managed to work on the table records which looks like : row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr"))
column_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")) and able to extract the cell values with the help of for loop. I  get the output on the console but when I try to export the data to an excel sheet with the help of OpenpyXl I get the below error related to module et_xmlfile not found

Answer (score 1):

You can try pandas read_html

```
tbl = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.tmptable").get_attribute('outerHTML')
dfs  = dfs.append(pd.read_html(tbl))
```

Answer (score 0):

[et_xmlfile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sEsU.png)

Openpyxl wont work because of this missing file. tried to install the et_xmlfile manually from https://pypi.org/project/et_xmlfile/ but still get the same error

Comment: error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'et_xmlfile'

Comment: 1) This should be an edit to your question, since you are not answering any part of it here. 2) I have no idea how to help, as you have included 0 snips of your code utilizing `openpyxl` and you are saying that is where the error is coming from. 3) Have you still not read my 2 linked posts regarding MCVE's, and expected formatting of questions? The community would really appreciate if you could go through those...please help us help you!